# How to set NA values from a matrix to black-coloured tiles in a ggplot heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, heatmap, geom-tile

I am working on the following structure and the following plotting code:

```
structure(c(NA, 11, 9, 9, 21, 7, 2, 5, 3, 0, 0, 1, 31, NA, 3, 
2, 1, 0, 0, 10, 3, 0, 0, 0, 31, 16, NA, 2, 2, 10, 0, 5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 59, 65, 1, NA, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 156, 23, 7, 17, 
NA, 3, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 31, 84, 0, 10, 16, NA, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2, 
0, 129, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41, 41, 0, 3, 4, 5, 
0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 16, 4, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 12, 2, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
NA, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(12L, 
12L), .Dimnames = list(c("WILL_", "WOULD_", "MAY_", "MIGHT_", 
"CAN_", "COULD_", "SHALL_", "SHOULD_", "MUST_", "OUGHT TO_", 
"USED TO_", "HAVE TO_"), c("_WILL", "_WOULD", "_MAY", "_MIGHT", 
"_CAN", "_COULD", "_SHALL", "_SHOULD", "_MUST", "_OUGHT TO", 
"_USED TO", "_HAVE TO")))
```

```
breaks <- c(0,1,5,10,50,100,500,100000)

reshape2::melt(structure, value.name = "Freq") %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(is.na(Freq) | Freq == 0, "", as.character(Freq))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Var2, fct_rev(Var1))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = Freq), color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_steps(low = "white", high = "purple", breaks = breaks, na.value = "grey",trans = "log")+ 
  scale_x_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0), position="top") +
  scale_y_discrete(NULL, expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=60,vjust = 0.5, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

I am trying to tweak the code so that original NA values (seen on the plot as the tiles forming a diagonal line from the co-occurrence of WILL WILL to HAVE TO HAVE TO, and the X HAVE TO column) are represented as black tiles separately from the other tiles which I would like to keep as they are.

Looking for tips on how to do this as I think I'm doing something wrong with the representation of values at the beginning of my code.

All the best

Cameron

Comment: One way would be to create a separate data set for the diagonal, and use it in a second `geom_tile` layer where fill is set to black. E.g. your data used in plot (minus the `rev`ing of factor levels): `d = expand.grid(x = letters[1:4], y = letters[1:4])`; `d$z = rnorm(nrow(d))`. Create data for diagonal: `d2 = d[d$x == d$y, ]`; Plot: `ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile() + geom_tile(data = d2, fill = "black")`

Comment: Thanks! That sounds doable but it still seems a bit manual to me. Like there's also the entire HAVE TO column which has NA values and which would need to be black

Comment: Sorry, missed the HAVE TO criterium. Just add another condition when you create "the black data": `d2 = d[d$x == d$y | d$x == "d", ]`

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately when I unreverse my factor the plot is flipped and I don't really want that.

Comment: And with the following code 

pasted plot code from my question +

````
d = expand.grid(x = letters[1:4], y = letters[1:4])
d$z = rnorm(nrow(d))
d2 = d[d$x == d$y | d$x == "d", ]
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile() + geom_tile(data = d2, fill = "black")
````
I get 2 successive plots, I don't suppose I'm ordering it correctly?

Comment: Well, `ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile() + geom_tile(data = d2, fill = "black")` gives _one_ plot. The first part: `ggplot(d, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_tile()` is a highly simplified version of your original. Then you just add second `geom_tile` which uses data 'd2' corresponding to (a) the diagonal and (b) a selected x-value, here 'd'. The fill of those tiles are set to black. When you write "a bit manual", do you have any _rule_ to programmatically select the 'x' value which should be black? Here I just hardcoded it to be a certain given column name.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it better now. I get an error when I try to add the second geom_tile : "Cannot find object Var2".

When I mentioned "manual", I meant I was looking for a rule to have the original NAs in my plot be always black in the output. But I suppose the solution we're working on now would be sufficient for my current needs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229561/discussion-between-cameron-and-henrik).

Comment: "to have the original NAs in my plot be always black in the output": then change `na.value` to black. But in your question you wrote: "...black tiles separately from the other tiles which I would like to _keep as they are_"...